# Why is full-laziness a default optimization?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Full laziness has been
[repeatedly](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-February/106673.html)
[demonstrated](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2015-December/122534.html)
to
[cause](https://github.com/michaelt/streaming/issues/6)
[space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321784/haskell-compiling-with-o2-drastically-increases-memory-usage/26322330#26322330)
[leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345095/what-is-the-correct-way-to-perform-constant-space-nested-loops-in-haskell/32359655#32359655).

Why is full laziness on from `-O` onwards?  I find myself unconvinced by the reasoning in SPJ's [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~as/fpcourse/slpj-book-1987.pdf).  The claim is that in

```
f = \y -> y + sqrt 4
```

`sqrt 4` is unnecessarily repeated each time `f` is entered so we should float it outside the lambda.  I agree in the small, but since we've seen what problems this transformation causes in the large I don't believe it is worth it.  It seems to me that the benefits of this transformation are obtainable unilaterally** with only local code changes and programmers who want it should implement it by hand.

Can you convince me otherwise?  Is `full-laziness` actually really useful?  I will be especially convinced if you can provide examples which to implement by hand require multilateral cooperation or non-local transformations.

** unlike optimizations like inlining and stream fusion which to implement by hand would require multilateral cooperation between modules and non-local code changes

Comment: The `full-laziness` transformantion doesn't actually have anything to do with evaluation order.

Comment: Another possible point against full laziness is from [this thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2014-August/006195.html).

Answer (score 14):

There's at least one common case where full laziness is "safe" and an optimization.

```
g :: Int -> Int
g z = f (z+1)
  where f 0 = 0
        f y = 1 + f (y-1)
```

This really means `g = \z -> let {f = ...} in f (z+1)` and, compiled that way, will allocate a closure for `f` before calling it. Obviously that's silly, and the compiler should transform the program into

```
g_f 0 = 0
g_f y = 1 + g_f (y-1)
g z = g_f (z+1)
```

where no allocation is needed to call `g_f`. Happily the full laziness transformation does exactly that.

Obviously programmers could refrain from making these local definitions that do not depend on the arguments of the top-level function, but such definitions are generally considered good style...

Another example:

```
h :: [Int] -> [Int]
h xs = map (+1) xs
```

In this case you can just eta reduce, but normally you can't eta reduce. And naming the function `(+1)` is quite ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  The same would apply if `f` were an `Int`, especially if calculating it is expensive.  However, I was thinking of a less violent transformation: `g = let {f = ...} in \z -> f (z+1)`.  This would still be considered good style I think, even if it doesn't fit syntactically as nicely with Haskell's `where`.

Comment: Your second example, `h`, is more convincing because giving a name to `(+1)` is indeed quite ugly.  I would assess it as being equivalent to SPJ's example with `sqrt 4`.  I guess my conclusion is then that `full-laziness` saves you from death by a thousand cuts.  One could in principle produce optimized versions by hand but it would be inefficient to do so everywhere.

Comment: Note that floating out lambdas should *always* be beneficial. Floating thunks or partial applications might have the ugly side-effects (retaining huge data structures that are cheap to reconstruct) you want to eliminate. It's a shame that GHC misses a flag for that.

Comment: @SebastianGraf I'm not sure what you mean that "floating out lambdas should always be beneficial". Might not a lambda capture thunks in a way that has ugly side effects? Or did you mean something else by "lambda", perhaps "lambda with no free variables"?

Comment: I meant that in floating out a lambda, you are floating out a normal-form, something that is cheap to eval. (Contrary to what I wrote above, I think floating out PAPs is OK, too, for the same reason.) If you float out a thunk it might *appear* as if that saves a lot of work when in reality it might be really cheap to recompute if it wasn't bound as a thunk in the first place. And if we enter the thunk at most once anyway, we haven't actually saved any work.

Comment: Of course you are right in that I completely disregarded closure growth in my assessment above. Any floated out binding means that the closure from whence it came will grow.